# Weird border in div background image

Tags: html, css

This weird border sometimes appears and later disappears. I attached the code in the link along with the screenshot. Each div have similar code. Also some background images have transparent color. It is usually fine in chrome and firefox  but appears in OS devices and in my android cellphone.

edit:
bug: http://postimg.org/image/kpmaqbh7x/full/

no bug: http://postimg.org/image/61eo0gq3l/

You might have to zoom in to see it.

sample code:

```
#div_room_107 {
    width: 15.6%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #8e8e8e;
    background-image: url(/staff-app/_/img/room_corners7.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin: .5% 0 .5% .5%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is important that you share your code, or even better, create a [**minimal, verifiable and concrete example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate your issue, which helps tremendously in formulating a specific problem statement that we can help diagnose. **p/s:** The image has an extremely poor resolution, and image-based code is highly discouraged (because it's not reproducible easily).

Comment: What border are you concerned with? I can't tell from your picture.

Comment: I updated the link. The host compressed it for some reason.

Comment: All of the boxes are borderless.

Comment: Link is still not enough — the image doesn't show the full context of your code, all styles that apply to the said element and more importantly, we cannot reproduce your problem because there's nothing to reproduce from.

Comment: Get rid of image link. It is fairly useless. Include your markup (HTML/CSS etc) and be more specific about this border you're seeing.

Comment: full sample code (no images): https://jsfiddle.net/h9j8aLd1/

Comment: It was cause by css artefacts. I was able to fix it by putting outline:1px solid black.